# Salesforce Role hierarchy

Tags: reporting, profile, roles, role-hierarchy, admin

Person A and Person B are under same profile(eg: Both are Sales Persons). Can Person A reports to Person C and Person B reports to Person D using role hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. Role Hierarchy can be effectively able to designed in following 2 ways,

Let assume in here `Person A` having manager as `Person C` and `Person B` having manager as `Person D`.

Design 1:

```
Person C (Let's say role "State 1")
----Person A (Let's say role "District 1") (Sales Person Profile)

Person D (Let's say role "State 2")
----Person B (Let's say role "District 2") (Sales Person Profile)
```

Design 2:

```
Person C, D (Let's say role "State")

-----Person A, B (Let's say role "District")(Sales Person Profile)
```

Both above 2 design is possible.`Role Hierarchy` and `Profile` assignment are different designs. You need to use those effectively.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you! What if C and D are in different profiles? eg: C is a manager and D is the director? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, Profile is used to provide access for the specific person. It's not interfere sales person and manager relation. As you mentioned whether person C is manager and D is director profile also they can able to view Person A and Person B records on above 2 designs :D.

Comment: Please mark it as  "answer" if that answer really answer your question. It's will help remaining users also which will having the same doubt in forward days.